# Unable to watch variables value at PhpStorm breakpoint

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I am facing a strange problem when I am debugging PhpStorm, I am using XAMPP + PhpStorm + Xdebug.

I write code below and set up 4 breakpoint

```
<?php
    $a=1;
    $b=2;
    $c=$a+$b;
    echo $c;
```

After I click listener button and debug button,Chrome visit `http://localhost/index.php`, the first break point is reached.

Then strange phenomenon is here:

1. I can not watch variables value of `$a`, `$b` and `$c`, no matter in debug window or I put mouse over these variables.
2. I click <kbd>F8</kbd>, the left 3 breakpoints will not reach. I have no idea where is the program's step now, but I know response is not return to Chrome because Chrome is still loading.
3. Even stranger, if I remove all breakpoints and not click listener button and not click debug button, Chrome load success, but once I click listener button and debug button, refresh Chrome, Chrome will load forever unless I stop listen and stop debug then Chrome will load success. That is wired; I have already uncheck 'break at first line', there is no breakpoints at all. I guess PhpStorm stuck somewhere, but I do not know where it is.

Can someone help me please,the other computer can debug success but this computer never debug success.

1) Show whole Xdebug log (share the file)

Xdebug log is here:https://www.dropbox.com/s/psfktprtl2jfftq/debug2.log?dl=0

And here is a yeserday ealier bigger log:https://www.dropbox.com/s/64jnwhscatjaihq/debug2-ealier.log?dl=0

2) PHP & Xdebug versions?

PHP and Xdebug version in picture below.

[image]

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image: c]

xdebug log

[image]

Comment: 1) Show whole Xdebug log (share the file) 2) PHP & Xdebug versions?

Comment: I have edit my question,there are xdebug log and php version,thank you very much!

Comment: What's you PhpStorm version? Somehow forgot to ask that last time. Xdebug 2.7 requires PhpStorm 2018.3.x or newer. So either upgrade PhpStorm to latest stable 2018.3.x or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: You are so nice,I downgrage Xdebug to 2.6.1,it is ok now,I can not believe,this problem frustrated me serval days,stackover is a nice pleace,full of expert,Ealier I use phpstrom 2018.1 ,then I change to phpstorm 2017.2 ,still not work,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xdebug 2.7 requires PhpStorm 2018.3.x or newer.

Either upgrade PhpStorm to latest stable 2018.3.x or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x. That will resolve the issue.