# Debugging with Xdebug Laravel Homestead and PhpStorm not hitting break points

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

I am trying to get debugging working in PhpStorm with Laravel and the Vagrant Homestead box.

So far I have everything set up correctly as far as I can tell but it won't stop at the breakpoints it only hits the `index.php`. This makes me think its a path mapping issue but I have these set up correctly.

Here is my config:

[image: xdebug.ini]

[image]

[image]

Path mappings:

[image]

IDE key has been set and correct server

[image]

This is an older version of PhpStorm so not sure if that could be the issue (version 2016.3) but as you can see my path mappings are setup for the root of the project so I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: You need PhpStorm **2018.3 or newer** if you want to debug with Xdebug 2.7 or newer (you have Xdebug 2.9.3). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61890459/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55161822/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159290/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160198/783119

Comment: could i not just switch to php 7.2 ? and am earlier version of xdebug?

Comment: switching php versions is easy but not sure how to downgrade xdebug to 2.6.x

Comment: Sadly I'm not using Homestead and therefore cannot help here. I may only suggest to upgrade your PhpStorm (so it better supports latest stuff etc). BTW: the next upcoming version of PhpStorm 2020.3 is currently in EAP stage which means that you can use it for free (as it comes with own 30 days license). If you want -- you may use it for a while (it will work separately to your current 2016.3, as long as you do not open the same project in both of them at the same time). Check https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/

Comment: yes may upgrade but dont really want to pay £80 for it after 30 days lol

Comment: The choice is yours -- there are other free IDEs or advanced text editors around there that can work with Xdebug. If you are not doing PHP dev work often or it's just a hobby etc then yes, it may not be worth it. Otherwise (my own experience) PhpStorm worth its money.